# How to convert one factor column in data.table to columns while keeping the other values?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

This is a bit hard to describe, so I would like to give an example.

Assume we have the following data.table: 
X, Y, Z are the attributes' names, and Y is column of factors, Z is a column of numerics

```
X  Y  Z
1  A  0.75
1  B  0.25
2  C  1
3  A  0.25
3  B  0.25
3  C  0.5
```

we would like to change the above table to the following (if there is no corresponding value, we just use 0):

```
X  A     B      C
1  0.75  0.25   0
2  0     0      1
3  0.25  0.25   0.5
```

So is there any function provided in data.table to handle this? or can anyone tell me how to do this efficiently?

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(X~Y, data=dat, fill=0)`

Comment: With `data.table` you can use the exact same code as for `reshape2`: `data.table::dcast(X ~ Y, data = dat, fill = 0)`

Comment: thank u guys, it works